# How to pass object from JavaScript/jQuery/angular to an action?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

Scenario:
I have a form and it has 10 fields, now I need to pass this 10 values to ASP.Net MVC Action.

Now on ng-click, I am posting this values to the action which in turn pass this values to DB.

Is there something like **object** in JavaScript/Angular?
I feel like its not safe to post this many parameters separately. 
 
***It would be great if there is some way to post this values as single object.***

Code Snippet

```
$scope.submit = function (p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10) {
    $http({}) 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your AngularJS controller, write `$scope.obj = {};` to create a scope object named `obj`. Now in your HTML, if you give any input field `ng-model="obj.p1"`, (where `p1` can be changed to just about anything), it will be bound to `$scope.obj.p1`. Do the same for `p2` through `p10`, and so your code snippet can be reimagined as below.

```
$scope.submit = function () {
  $http.post(url, $scope.obj); //<- $scope.obj = { p1: 'something', 'p2': 'something', ...}
}
```

Hope that was helpful!

Comment: mate I am getting values in $scope.abj ={} but how do I access this JavaScript object in my action, because I am thinking if its possible to map this javascript object to C# object..I want my action to accept one parameter and that to be an object. Can you please tell me something on this?

Comment: Wrap it in an object and send it. Update `$http.post` to say `$http.post(url, { object: $scope.obj });`. This will send the entire object to your backend.

Answer (score 0):

```
$http.post(url, {Foo:"some foo", Bar:"some bar"});
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to set up a model in your .NET application like this:

```
public class MyModel{
 public string Foo {get; set;}
 public string Bar {get; set'}
}
```

Your MVC controller should allow `POST` and should accept this model as an argument.

Now, in Angular, just use `$http` service:

```
$http.post([Your MVC URL], {Foo:"some foo", Bar:"some bar"});
```

Good luck!

Comment: He was asking about objects in Javascript. Also, your angular code is incorrect. The URL comes before the parameters.

Comment: @Tejas--You are correct about the Angular portion, it has been adjusted.